# Counting occurance of a value in SQL results set in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, resultset

Suppose I have a table of people with firstname lastname sex natinoality etc.

I want to count the number of male and number of females.

I can do two SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM people WHERE sex = 'male'
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM people WHERE sex = 'female'
```

However can I do one query:

```
SELECT * FROM people
```

Then count the number of occurance of 'male' and 'female'?
Is looping through the entire result set the only way?

Edit: The reason I am asking this is because of performance. I will have multiple JOIN and the table size is over 2k rows. Moreover, I will not be only counting sex, I will also be counting nationality, age, language, and many other columns.

I just want to make sure I am selecting an approach that will use the minimum amount of resources. I don't want the query and the PHP script to take ages to run.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by grouping the `sex` column, and aggregating other columns by using the `COUNT( )` function.

```
SELECT   sex, 
         COUNT(*) GenderCount
FROM     people
GROUP BY sex
```

PS: kindly change the name of your column to `Gender` rather than `sex`.. hehehe

**[Some Additional Information for Aggregate Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)**
 and **[HERE](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx)**

Comment: If I have 10 things I want to count, including gender, would it be wise to run the above query 10 separate times? I have multiple JOIN so I am worried about the performance.

Comment: no but you can still do it on a single query, eg: `SELECT COUNT(sex), COUNT(GENDER)....` depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
select SUM(sex='male') AS countmale, SUM(sex='female') AS countfemale from people
```

Answer (score 0):

to get output in one row you can try this:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(sex = 'male', 1, 0)) AS male_count,
       SUM(IF(sex = 'female', 1, 0)) AS fe_male_count
FROM people;
```

to get multiple rows output try this:

```
SELECT sex, COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM people
GROUP BY sex;
```

however I think that `GROUP BY` query will be faster.